# How can i render PageNotFound.js if i am not provinding parameter value to URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

When i am clicking on the link(having key containing auth token) which i am getting in my mail,it is redirecting me to Update password page.But I don't want to redirect it if a user is just entering the URL.

[http://localhost:3000/update-password?key=ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFh] should redirect to Change Password page and [http://localhost:3000/update-password] should redirect to PageNotFound page.i hope you'll understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow three steps:

1. Get current `search` from `react-router`:

   ```
   const {
      location: { search }
   } = propsFromReactRouter
   ```
2. Check, does `search` contain key. You can do it with https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string on mannualy.

   ```
   import { parse } from 'query-string';
   const searchData = parse(search);

   const { key } = searchData;
   ```
3. if search doesn't contain key, redirect to not found page

   ```
   import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
   // ...
   return (
       <Redirect to="/404" />
   )
   ```